# \cline goes through tabular/array cell with left margin

Tags: tables

`\cline` uses TeX primitive `\hrule` and it doesn't stop stretching if the next column has extra margin at its left hand side. It simply reaches the leftest edge of the next column's content, not the rightest edge of the column itself.

```
\begin{tabular}{l|@{\hspace{10em}}l}
a & b  \\
\cline{1-1}
c & d
\end{tabular}
```

The above example shows the situation. 
[image]

I expect it should stop at the vertical bar, though. So my question is; are there any ways to stop stretching the \cline?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve what you're after. But perhaps you can provide some context, since a (proper) solution might depend on this information.

Comment: The space added on the right of a column is considered part of that column (as you just saw), with that piece of knowledge that is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Try `\begin{tabular}{l|>{\hspace*{10em}}l}`.

Comment: @Werner I could find out a trick just to somehow achieve the "expected" result in some given context, like adding vacant column with 10em width. I wanted to know if there's a way to make `\cline` stick with the exact column.

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, it's an expected behaviour from TeX point of view, but IMHO is a kind of betraying what people expect for table columns.

Comment: @Bernard I'm afraid it won't.

Comment: It won't what? For me it works…

Comment: @keiichiroshikano: How about creating two `tabular`s side-by-side with a `10em` space between them?

Comment: @Bernard Sorry for that, it actually works! I had a complete misunderstanding...

Comment: @Werner That must be another workaround, thank you. Fortunately, Bernard gave a thorough solution!

Comment: @Bernard ``{l|@{}>{\hspace*{10em}}l}`` for maintaining distances as in original

Comment: @jfbu: That's what I had written initially, but I don't think so  as you can see from comparing with second solution which has the original distance.

Comment: @Bernard I tested now adding to your MWE a third solution using `{l|@{}>{\hspace{10em}}l}` and it appears to give exact same layout (at least horizontally) as your second solution (tested with `\usepackage[grid]{eso-pic}`)

Comment: Yes, of course, `|@{}>{\hspace{10em}}` and `|>{\hspace*{\dimexpr10em-\tabcolsep}}` produce the same result.

Comment: @Bernard, so isn't it simpler to use `{l|@{}>{\hspace{10em}}l}`? I do not get what you mean in your [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449566/cline-goes-through-tabular-array-cell-with-left-margin?noredirect=1#comment1129758_449566) above.

Comment: I had overlooked the `@{}`  in the code proposed in your first comment. You're perfectly right, it's simpler, and I'll incorporate it in my first code, if you don't mind (with due credit, of course).

Comment: @Bernard please go ahead and +1 anyway! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions. The first was simplified by @jfbu (many thanks for his comments!). The second uses the trimming capabilities of `\cmidrule` in the `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, hhline, multirow,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|@{}>{\hspace*{10em}}l}
a & b \\
\cline{1-1}
c & d
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

{\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{l|@{\hspace{10em}}l}
a & b \\
\cmidrule(r{10em}){1-1}
c & d
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to separate the content into two `tabular`s. You may have to play around with the vertical alignment, depending on what the `tabular`s contain, but that can be done.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l |}
  a \\
  \hline
  c
\end{tabular}%
\hspace{10em}%
\begin{tabular}{ l }
  b \\
  d
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```